# How can I fold all ChildView Group in Android ExpandableList Item?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can I fold all ChildView Group in `Expandable List`. Now I have two buttons to control Expand All and Fold All on Activity. Expandable button is OK and it is working work but I don't know how to fold all ChildView Group. How can i do this ?

Thanks

```
**expandableListView.expandGroup(position, true); = OK<Br>

expandableListView.foldGroup(position) = ? or ?**
```

Comment: I found a solution to fold is just call method, collapseGroup(position).

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
int count = (new ExpAdapter(this)).getGroupCount();
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    expList.collapseGroup(i);
                }

            }
        });
```